# How to find all occurrences when a prefix is present

Tags: python, regex, iterator

I am looking for repeating patterns inside an HTML page.
The patterns I am interested in start after the prefix "<h2>Seasons</h2>"
The same patterns occur before the prefix too, I am not interested in those.

I tried (and failed) with the following python code (I simplified the pattern to '<a href=.+?</a>' for the sake of making this question readable):

```
matches = re.compile('<h2>Seasons</h2>.+?(<a href=.+?</a>)+',re.DOTALL).findall(page)  
for ref in matches  
   print ref
```

Given the  page:

```
blah blah html stuff 
<h2>Seasons</h2>  
blah blah  more html stuff
<a href=http://www.111.com>111</a><a href=http://www.222.com>222</a><a href=http://www.333.com>333</a>
```

The output is

```
<a href=http://www.333.com>333</a>
```

So it only prints the last match, the other two do not make it to the findall list.
How do I do to iterate over all matches of the groups?

Comment: This may be the problem: http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with a regex when there are many great HTML parsers that will do the job better and make it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the regex matches only a single time. The parenthesized group matches multiple times, but the regex as a whole only matches once. This means only one match is returned, the last one.

To get around this you need to write a regex that matches multiple times. You might think to use a lookbehind assertion for the `<h2>` element like so:

```
(?<=<h2>Seasons</h2>.+?)(<a href=.+?</a>)    # doesn't work
```

This says to find `<a>` elements, but only if they're preceded by `<h2>Seasons</h2>`. Unfortunately lookbehind strings have to be of fixed length. You can't put `.+?` in a lookbehind assertion. So that approach is out.

Next up is to find the location of the `<h2>` element first, then perform the regex search starting from there.

```
>>> re.findall('<a href=.+?</a>', page[page.find('<h2>Seasons</h2>'):], re.DOTALL)
['<a href=http://www.111.com>111</a>', '<a href=http://www.222.com>222</a>', '<a href=http://www.333.com>333</a>']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an html parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/); will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I think an HTML parser is too much for what I am trying to do